# Linux terminal pipe to my C++ program

Tags: c++, linux

I'm not sure about the terminology, and when I googled this I got many misleading results. I just need a push and I'll be fine.

How can put my program as a target to piping in linux terminal?

Say I wrote a C++ program MyProg

I would like to be able to do something like

$ ls | ./MyProg

Could you please give me a hint to what function/stream can be used for this?

Comment: reading from standard input (std::cin) should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piping, as you call it, is nothing special in Linux, that's why you do not find it.

What the pipe does is to redirect the standard output (`stdout`) of one program to the standard input (`stdin`) of another. So simply read the standard input, and you will find the text there. You an use `std::cin` if you want to go the C++ way, or `*scanf()` in C mode.

If you want to know if `stdin` refers to the actual terminal or some redirection, you can use `isatty(0)` (0 is the fd of stdin, there is a constant somewhere but I can't remember the name, while everybody know that stdin is 0).

Answer (score 1):

You should handle standard input **(stdin)**, output **(stdout)** and error **(stderr)** in your application. They have reserved file descriptor numbers. Please refer to following link [File descriptor Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)